# Chrome do not show the network request list in the network panel

Tags: google-chrome

My Chrome do not show the network request list:

[image]

you see my snapshot, in the network panel when I refresh the web page, there do not list the request list.

Answer (score 11):

Your preferences have probably become corrupted.

You may reset the preferences by either:

- In the Dev Tools Settings, Preferences tab, scroll down and click
  "Restore defaults and reload"
- Run `localStorage.clear()` in the Console tab

Comment: That was awesome.
Any reason why this happens?
It is super annoying to have to do this, why should I have to reset defaults?
What is happening to cause this issue?
Or is it a case of I changed something?

Comment: @TheArchitecta: Too many possibilities : User action, extensions, browser bug and more.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the "Restore defaults and reload" worked for me. Did not have to clear local storage.

Comment: @SarathSMenon: You're welcome. Only one of the two actions is theoretically required.

Answer (score 11):

I see your Filter tab is red, so there is no filtered data in it.

you should check if your Filter is selected suitable controls:

[image]

check `All` should be log the HTTP request right. 
if you check `Doc`, `Manifest`, when you HTTP request, there maybe no logs.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is from last year, but in case anyone else stumbles on this:

@aircraft was mistaken. The filter is red, which means there is something in the filter search box that doesn't match any of the results, you just can't see the search box. Click the filter to show the search box, delete the contents, all of the network requests will then show up.

Answer (score 2):

I none of the above works try this(it worked for me):

**Step 1:**

[image]

**Step 2:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To filter requests by type, click the "Filter" icon than you can see that bar